# How do I grab a header from this page with either BS4 or Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am quite new at this and am challenging myself to my first useful project beyond tic tac toe games and text based choose your own adventure games. Im trying to write a script which will show when the base price of some houses increases past their current values then send a sms to me saying it has increased. For now, I just need help getting the price to print in pycharm using either BS4 or Selenium. so far I have gotten selenium to find and open the page. When I inspect the Base Price element on the page it comes back as :

```
> "<h3 ng-show="model.mod_basePrice" class="ng-binding"> Base Price
> $278,900</h3>"
```

. I have tried everything I can find to get it to display the header or price. Ive been at this all day long. Im missing something and Im getting nowhere.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.legacyhomesal.com/pennington-freedom-series-richmond-ii")
price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(name='ng-binding')
print(price)
```

I have tried each of these and more:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name(name='ng-binding')
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ng-binding')
driver.find_element_by_class_name(name='ng-binding')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('ng-binding')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='page']/section[2]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/aside/h3")
```

I created my own Xpath as well. When I inspect the base price element on the page, and find //h3[@class='ng-binding' it does highlight the correct element so at least I know the xpath works. I tried the following with no results as well:

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="//h3[@class='ng-binding']")
print(price)
```

The result I get back with the above is:

```
C:\Users\kgood\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe "C:/Users/kgood/Desktop/Legacy R2 Price.py"
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="0c6f3462267a3648682858dc0fd0d3c4", element="fdddf0be-c2ca-4466-996f-caac9d31e269")>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Try price.text. Should output Base Price $278,900.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the following to print the innerhtml.

```
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@class='ng-binding']")
print(price.text)
```

Also use webdriver waits for a more stable find.

```
price=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='ng-binding']")))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the *text* `Base Price $278,900` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.legacyhomesal.com/pennington-freedom-series-richmond-ii')
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h3.ng-binding[ng-show='model.mod_basePrice']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.legacyhomesal.com/pennington-freedom-series-richmond-ii')
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h3[@class='ng-binding']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.legacyhomesal.com/pennington-freedom-series-richmond-ii')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.ng-binding[ng-show='model.mod_basePrice']"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.legacyhomesal.com/pennington-freedom-series-richmond-ii')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='ng-binding']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Base Price $278,900
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)